# database table structure to store user location

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

I have a requirement to store user's proper location & send them newsletters as per them, I would like to understand the best way to store them as I have been finding it challenging to retrieve it after storing.

First of all, the address that needs to be stored is like:-
Country1-City1-SocietyName1-AnyMoreSmallLocation1-...so on.

So, now what I have done so far...

Table 1...

```
PID Place Parent
1   Country1    0
2   Country2    0
3   City1       1
4   City2       1
5   City3       2
6   Society1    3
```

n so on

Then

User table where I am keeping location with UID

```
UID  Name  PID
1.   John    6
2.   Sam     7
```

But at the get call of user location it needs to be like this...society name, city, country. which seems not good as per current design..please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If each user has only one adress, consider having only one table :

```
UID  Name  Country   City   etc.
```

But if there is multiple adresses per user, 2 tables (User and Adress):

```
UID  Name
AdresseID  UID  Country   City   etc.
```

Comment: It will cause a lot of redundant data if i store everything as a string for each user which will be a bad idea. And yes only one address

Comment: Well why are you storing the name ? Since it's also redudant. The only thing to put in another table would be the country.